# One of my user getting the task automatically with nulll details

Tags: community, profile, tasks

One of my user getting the task automatically with null details .there are two to three fields in tasks are compulsory .i am sending the photo copy to look show how it is .can we able to find out.from where it is created[image: here is the task how it is shown]

the task was created but it was not assigned to any one

Answer (score 1):

Need some more information to figure this one out. Do you have any triggers that are running or workflow rules that create tasks? What does the Created By field on the task say? Have you installed any AppExchange add-ons recently? Those would be the first places to check to figure out the cause.

Also, if it's showing up in "My Tasks" it's assigned to the user that's looking at it.